# Problem with variable recognition in Fortran

Tags: variables, fortran

i am a complete beginner at Fortran and am working on a code that solves a kinetic mechanism by solving differential equations at different time steps using a differential equation solver.
Here is a link to download the zip file with the whole project:

http://www.filedropper.com/fortranmicropyrolyzersetup

The input variables for the differential solver are defined as follows in the code:

```
     ! Declaration of variables
     implicit none
     EXTERNAL                   ::  FEXSB_AUTO, JEX_SB
     integer                    ::  neq,Mf,lrw,liw,iwork,itol,itask,istate,iopt     !solver parameters                
     integer                    ::  j,jjk,m                                         !Counters
     double precision           ::  ATOL,RTOL, RWORK                                !solver parameters
     double precision           ::  T, TOUT                                         !starting time (s), timestep time (s)
     double precision           ::  Y, w                                            !molar fraction of biomass (-), mass fraction of biomass (-)
     double precision           ::  y_gas, w_gas, Conc                              !molar fraction in gas phase (-), concentration in gas phase (mol/m³), mass fraction in gas phase (-)
     double precision           ::  n(speciescount)                                 !number of moles (used temporarily to calculate initial molar fracions)  
     character*5                ::  simulationNumber


  !Setting the solver parameters
     neq = SpeciesCount         !number of equations
     ITOL = 1                   !RTOL and ATOL are integers
     RTOL = 1.0D-8               !Relative tolerance
     ATOL = 1.0D-15              !Absolute tolerance
     ITASK = 1                  
     ISTATE = 1
     LRW = 22 +  9*SpeciesCount + 2*SpeciesCount**2                  !Array sizing (see VODE)
     LIW = 30+SpeciesCount                                         !Array sizint (see VODE)
     MF = 22                    !Use BDF with finite difference Jacobian
     IOPT = 1                   !Optional input specified
     Iwork(6) = 7000            !Increase maximum iteration steps from 500 to 2000 otherwise the solver does not converge
```

The differential solver is then called in a do loop for each time step as follows:

```
  ! Solve reactor equations (see FEXSB) and advance time, until stop criterium is met
     TimeStep = 0   ! dimensionless time step
     !DO while(wm(1).lt.0.9999) -> previously used stop criterium
     DO while((y_gas(1).lt.0.99999).OR.(TimeStep.lt.10))        !stop criterium: molar fraction Helium = 0.9999 AND do at least 100 timesteps
         TimeStep = TimeStep + 1
         write(*,*)"Doing iteration for time step",TimeStep
         call DVODE(FEXSB_AUTO,NEQ,Y,T,TOUT,ITOL,RTOL,ATOL,ITASK,ISTATE,IOPT,RWORK,LRW,IWORK,LIW,JEX_SB,MF)     !solve reactor equations to Y
        !CALL DVODE(FEXSB_AUTO,NEQ,Y,T,TOUT,ITOL,RTOL,ATOL,ITASK,ISTATE,IOPT,RWORK,LRW,IWORK,LIW,JEX_SB,MF,RPAR,IPAR)

        ! calculate w, y_gas, w_gas and Conc from Y
        do j = 1, SpeciesCount

            if (Y(j) .lt. 1.0D-10) then      ! round to zero below 10e-10 to avoid negative numbers and numerical problems with small numbers
                Y(j) = 0.0D0
            endif
            if (MolarFlowRate(j) .lt. 1.0D-10) then
                MolarFlowRate(j) = 0.0D0
            endif
            w(j) = Y(j)*n0_tot*amms(j) / (mass_sample)
            y_gas(j) = MolarFlowRate(j) / TotalMolarFlowRate
            w_gas(j) = MolarFlowRate(j)*amms(j) / (1000*MassFlowRate) ! factor 1000 to put molar mass in kg/mol instead of g/mol
            Conc(j) = MolarFlowRate(j) / VolumetricFlowRate

        end do
```

The differential equation solver does not successfully complete the do loop of the line :

`DO while((y_gas(1).lt.0.99999).OR.(TimeStep.lt.10))`

The variables seem to be recognized for the first time step when the ODE Solver is called in the line:

`call DVODE(FEXSB_AUTO,NEQ,Y,T,TOUT,ITOL,RTOL,ATOL,ITASK,ISTATE,IOPT,RWORK,LRW,IWORK,LIW,JEX_SB,MF)`

And the solver successfully completes the first iteration. After the time step is increased one more time, the call function works again but this time the variables are not recognized somehow. When I stop the code to debug what is wrong after the first time step, I realized that the variables required for DVODE do not have set values anymore, somehow they get deleted after the first successful iteration.

What might be causing this problem?

```
*DECK DVODE
      SUBROUTINE DVODE (F, NEQ, Y, T, TOUT, ITOL, RTOL, ATOL, ITASK,
     1            ISTATE, IOPT, RWORK, LRW, IWORK, LIW, JAC, MF,
     2            RPAR, IPAR)
      EXTERNAL F, JAC
      DOUBLE PRECISION Y, T, TOUT, RTOL, ATOL, RWORK, RPAR
      INTEGER NEQ, ITOL, ITASK, ISTATE, IOPT, LRW, IWORK, LIW,
     1        MF, IPAR
      DIMENSION Y(*), RTOL(*), ATOL(*), RWORK(LRW), IWORK(LIW),
     1          RPAR(*), IPAR(*)
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
c dvode: Variable-coefficient Ordinary Differential Equation solver,
! with fixed-leading-coefficient implementation.
! This version is in double precision.
!
! DVODE solves the initial value problem for stiff or nonstiff
! systems of first order ODEs,
!     dy/dt = f(t,y) ,  or, in component form,
!     dy(i)/dt = f(i) = f(i,t,y(1),y(2),...,y(NEQ)) (i = 1,...,NEQ).
! DVODE is a package based on the EPISODE and EPISODEB packages, and
! on the ODEPACK user interface standard, with minor modifications.
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
! Authors:
!               Peter N. Brown and Alan !. Hindmarsh
!               Center for Applied Scientific Computing, L-561
!               Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory
!               Livermore, CA 94551
! and
!               George D. Byrne
!               Illinois Institute of Technology
!               Chicago, IL 60616
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I am new to Fortran. If I should supply any additional information to help you answer my question, please don't hesitate to let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is.  You make an observation about the failure of your debugger to show you the values of variables during a 2nd iteration.  But you stop short of telling us that the code fails to solve the problem or that the code does not run to completion.  If the 'problem' is just that you have a broken debugger, get another one.  If that isn't the problem be much more explicit about what is.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope this makes the problem more clear for you.

Comment: It would be good, if you can show a compilable and testable example and show us the values that those arguments have after the first call. Does DVODE mentions in the documentation that any of them is supposed to be destroyed? If not, it could be a case of stack corruption.

Comment: I added a link to a zip file with the whole project in my question, so you can have a better idea of the exact issue and how to solve it. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Please do not do that here. Make a [mcve] that fits here, do not upload a zip file to an external link that may become invalid in a few months or years. The questions and answers here should remain useful for future visitors. Also, requesting people studying a large project is too much. It is enough to make a short testing program that calls `DVODE` in a loop. It should not take more than, say, 50 lines, probably less.

Comment: What we do need to know is what DVODE documentation promises about the arguments. I even tried to download the code, but they require registering and there are multiple versions. So it is vital,that you copy and paste the header from the source file that describes the role of each argument. Not the full source code of DVODE, if it is long, just the description of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption that the parameters should be untouched after the first iteration is wrong.

In fortran function parameters are always passed by reference. Thus, a fortran function never guarantees that your original parameter set is the same after the call. It might be the intened (or poor) design of the function to DO change the parameters. Only documentation can help you, and what you provided in your question is not enough, which might very likely also mean: maybe there is not enough documentation for this case/function.

In contrast to C/C++ in fortran there is no "const" modifier for variables that would guarantee you what you have to assume right now.

To me it seem the only solution is to re-initialize all parameters right before every call to DVODE.

Comment: Certainly not *always*. *"The only parameter passing mechanism endorsed by Real Programmers is call-by-value-return, as implemented in the IBM/370 Fortran G and H compilers."* And there are more possibilities.

Comment: *'C/C++ in fortran there is no "const"'* We have `intent(in)` and `value`.